# Duplex WCF service not supported in UWP?

Tags: c#, wcf, uwp, duplex

How can I use a duplex WCF service in my UWP app?

Every time I create a `InstanceContext` it throws `PlatformNotSupportedExcetpion: Operation is not supported on this platform.`

I have two applications that share the same code to connect to the WCF service. One of them is a UWP app, the other one a normal Desktop app.

```
var callback = new JuqeServiceCallback();
var binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None) { MaxBufferSize = 10485760, MaxBufferPoolSize = 10485760, MaxReceivedMessageSize = 10485760 };
var address = new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost/Juqe/Service.svc");
var factory = new DuplexChannelFactory<IJuqeService>(new InstanceContext(callback), binding, address); // PlatformNotSupported exception gets thrown
```

**The interfaces:**

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IJuqeServiceCallback))]
public interface IJuqeService {...}
public interface IJuqeServiceCallback {...}
```

**The callback:**

```
[CallbackBehavior]
public class JuqeServiceCallback : IJuqeServiceCallback {...}
```

**Side notes:**

*NETCore.UniversalWindowsVersion version:* 5.2.2

*Target/Min version:* 10.0; Build 10586

*.NET version:* 4.6.1

*Visual Studio version:* 2015

I followed the solutions from this question: [How to consume duplex wcf service in Windows Universal App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33146457/how-to-consume-duplex-wcf-service-in-windows-universal-app)

They didn't worked.

I also created a new, blank UWP app (Traget/min version 10.0; Build 14393), updated the NETCore.UniversalWindowsVersion to 5.2.2 and tried it again. Same error.

There is the option to update the NETCore..UniversalWindowsVersion to 5.3 but I have to install VS 2017 for it. Will this fix the error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to consume duplex wcf service in Windows Universal App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33146457/how-to-consume-duplex-wcf-service-in-windows-universal-app)

Comment: Like I said: I tried it, it didn't work.